# Call SQL View | Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

The data I want to return from the database, needs a quite complicated query. If the query is quite simple in SQL (join of 4 tables), using LINQ for me it is quite impossible.

I thought about creating a table view. My question is, do I need to create a model to return data from this view? Or what is the proper way to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: No one can start with Entity Framework without knowing how to use Linq. Before you ask that do you need a model, you have to understand what the model can do first.

Comment: How about passing that as raw sql itself. I believe 4 join on the tables is not very expensive in EF if you apply correct filters

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure what you mean by proper way, but what you are trying to achieve is to abstract the SQL logic away from your application and in the end read from the view, then yes. I think entity framework will require a key to be explicitly specified though

```
public class YourView
{
    [Key]
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write to google "Entity Framework", it will return you "Entity Framework, . Net platformunda ORM (Object Relational Mapping) ". This mean that Entity Framework work with object models. First of all , you must create a data model, after that you can use raw sql or what do you want.
Here is a link for Entity Framework
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/what-is-entityframework.aspx